# How to customize Compodoc Angular documentation?

Tags: angular, npm, code-documentation, compodoc

I have tried to add additional side nav menus with existing compodoc documentation.

I could do that like below.

menu-wc.js

```
<li class="link">
    <a href="dependencies.html" data-type="chapter-link">
       <span class="icon ion-ios-list"></span>Custom Change
    </a>
</li>
```

When we update our documentation using this npm command

```
compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

The changes were gone. The main-wc.js file creating newly every time this command executed.

is there any way we can customize the compodoc documentation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Compodoc supports adding new side menu elements, linking to existing markdown files
  * https://compodoc.app/guides/tips-and-tricks.html#additional-documentation

Also, linking to actual usage examples for each component is an effective tool

- https://compodoc.app/guides/live-example-tab.html